# Correct way to look up Hostnames in Qt with QHostInfo or QDnsLookUp

Tags: c++, dns, qt5, qhostaddress

I am trying to use `QHostInfo` or `QDnsLookUp` to look up a hostname and get a list of [QHostAddress](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhostaddress.html). I would prefer [QHostInfo](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhostinfo.html) (the interface is simpler) but I tried also [QDnsLookUp](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdnslookup.html).

In the first case, I use `QHostInfo::lookupHost()` static function, and then I get the addresses from the result with `QHostInfo::addresses()`

In the second case I use `QDnsLookup::lookup()`, with the type set to `QDnsLookup::A` (IPv4 address records) and I get the results with `QDnsLookup::hostAddressRecords()` (and I get the value of the `QDnsHostAddressRecord` elements).

Well, both methods work somehow, but I get only one result...in both cases it should be a list of results from the documentation...but my list contains only one element...

Is there some option or something else that I should set to get the complete list? What could have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of [Dig - Google Apps](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/) I found out that the `QDnsLookup::A` option was not the correct solution. I have to use `QDnsLookup::ANY` in order to have a complete list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store result in a list, some examples:

```
QString myClass::getBroadWiFiAddress()
{
    QString ipAddress;
    QNetworkInterface wifi;
    // Get WiFi interface
     QList<QNetworkInterface> interfceList = QNetworkInterface::allInterfaces();
     for (int i = 0; i < interfceList.size(); ++i)
     {

         if (interfceList.at(i).name().contains("wireless") && interfceList.at(0).isValid() && interfceList.at(i).IsUp)
         {
             //qDebug() << "Interfaces:" << i << interfceList.at(i).name() << " / " << interfceList.at(i).humanReadableName();
             wifi = interfceList.at(i);
            break;
         }

     }

    QList<QHostAddress> ipAddressesList = wifi.allAddresses();
    // use the first non-localhost IPv4 address
    for (int i = 0; i < ipAddressesList.size(); ++i) {
        if (ipAddressesList.at(i) != QHostAddress::LocalHost &&
            ipAddressesList.at(i).toIPv4Address() ) {
            ipAddress = ipAddressesList.at(i).toString();
            //qDebug() << "Using following IP Address:" << ipAddress;
            break;
        }
    }
    //qDebug() << "getBroadWiFiAddress" << ipAddress;
    return ipAddress;
}
```

Comment: Hi Mohammad, I do not understand your answer...You are not using QDnsLookUp, nor QHostInfo in your example...I obviously store them in a list, the Qt functions themselves give me a list, but that list contains only 1 result, that is my problem...

Comment: @n3mo, because I think the methods you mentioned may not necessarily return the list you wish, are you sure all addresses you want back are associated with same hostname .. the code I provided gets a list of interfaces and a list of addresses for a particular interface .. then you check the other way back, as the hostname of intereset may be associated only with a single address .. you might check

Comment: Yes, I checked with `dig` in Linux, the hostname has something like 30-40 addresses :)